# How to determine when message was sent in Akka

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am wondering if there is the possibility to know when a message has been delivered. Since I want to shutdown the actorsystem right afterwards. The code below connects to a remote actor and then sends a message. But in some cases the local actorsystem seems to be shut down too early.

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("Test", config.getConfig("webbackend"));
ActorSelection communicator = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://Midas@127.0.0.1:2555/user/Communicator");
communicator.tell(new TimerTransmissionCmd(channel.getId()), ActorRef.noSender());
//system.shutdown();
```

Comment: Why not to send an acknowledgement from a remote actor in reply to TimerTransmissionCmd and wait for it before shutdown the actor system?

Comment: If you tell me how to actually wait for it. The call is within a rest endpoint's method

Comment: You can use [Akka ask pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html#use-with-actors) to get a Future for the result. And if your REST endpoint doesn't work with Future-s directly then you can use Await.result to wait for the result (if you are sure that you want to block) or onComplete / onSuccess / onFailure callbacks.

Comment: Can you provide an answer with sample code? :)

Comment: You should definitely not create one ActorSystem per REST call, that is a very expensive operation. ActorSystems are supposed to run for a long time, serving many requests; you can for example create a new actor for every request (and stop it when done, of course).

Comment: What is the difference between a rest call and a request in your opinion? I already thought of this , too. But did not know where to set the actor system up within a java servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code after send the message:

```
Boolean wasProcessed = (Integer)Await.result(Patterns.ask(communicator, new ResultClass(), 5000), 
            Duration.create(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

if(wasProcessed){
    actorSystem.shutdown();
}
```

You also have to add this in your Actor class:

```
private boolean wasProcessed = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Object messageReceived) throws Exception {
    if (messageReceived instanceof ResultClass) {
        this.workerActor1.tell(wasProcessed, getSender());
    } else {
        //Put your process code here
        wasProcessed = true;
    }
}
```

But I recommend you configure a prudential timeout and after that always shutdown the system.